# How to pass $(this) to function on .get in jquery?

Tags: jquery, get, this

I have:

```
    function dosomething(data) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
    $(this).children('img').attr('title', data) 
}

$('.test').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $.get('/inc/ajax-function.asp?action=check', dosomething);

})
```

Now this obviously doesn't work. What I would like to do is this:

When the .get is called get rresult into data (this works) and put the result in title of the img that is a children of the link that you mouseover. How do I get the $(this) value to the function?

```
<a class='test' href='book.asp><img src='image.gif' title='' /></a>
```

Thank you for 2 good solutions. I don't know which one is "better" that is faster and more "standard" to use in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jQuery proxy function for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Try this:

```
$('.test').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $.get('/inc/ajax-function.asp?action=check', $.proxy(dosomething, this));
})
```

Comment: Not sure about performance, but this one is definitely cleaner than my answer

Answer (score 7):

Use the closure you're already creating for the `mouseover` handler:

```
$('.test').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var elm = this;
    $.get('/inc/ajax-function.asp?action=check', function(data) {
        dosomething.call(elm, data);
    });
});
```

Your `get` callback will have access to the `elm` local, and then we call `dosomething` via `Function#call` (which makes the first argument we pass to `call` be `this` during the call to the function). (This is what jQuery's `$.proxy` does for you behind the scenes, create a closure and call the function via `Function#call` or `Function#apply`, but as you have a closure lying around anyway, may as well use it directly. Still, +1 to Chandu, `$.proxy` is a perfectly fine way to do this.)

Or modify your `dosomething` to accept the element as an argument, and you don't have to use `Function#call`:

```
function dosomething(elm, data) {
    alert($(elm).attr('class'))
    $(elm).children('img').attr('title', data) 
}

$('.test').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var elm = this;
    $.get('/inc/ajax-function.asp?action=check', function(data) {
        dosomething(elm, data);
    });
});
```